# How to compress pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, compression, pymupdf

I'm trying to figure out how to compress a 228MB pdf file(2249pages),

have been manually compressed (medium-leavel) to 20MB using ilovepdf-tool, but ilovepdf is charged and I have to use automated implementation,

I have used pymupdf lossless compression once to reach 154 MB.

```py
doc.save(output_path,garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True, deflate_images=True,deflate_fonts=True)
```

**but it is still too large.**

I want to compress to less than 100MB, and less than 20MB is better

is there any better compression method?

Comment: maybe it may need to extract images, convert them to `JPG`, and put them again into PDF. Or don't use `lossless` compression.

Comment: From 154 MB to 20 MB? Forget it - this is simply not achievable. You could remove images completely, or replace them with their grayscale version (all that is possible with PyMuPDF), but a reduction by a **_factor of 8_** ... illusive without getting rid of the images altogether.